# jQuery Ajax post submitting multiple times over

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, post

I just cannot understand why this form sends multiple copies of the same email (anywhere from 1-8 copies). I've tried my best to trouble shoot the problem but I can't figure it out.

I'm using jQuery Validation Engine to validate the form, and if it validates correctly, I use jquery.post() to submit the form.

I've included all of my code, just to be safe. But there's some stuff that probably doesn't matter here, like the ppcconversion script I load in an iframe when the message is successfully sent.

See the code below:

```
$(".consult-form form .submit").click(function(){
    $(".consult-form form").validationEngine('attach', {
        promptPosition : "topLeft",
        onValidationComplete: function(contactForm, status){
            if(status==true){
                $(".consult-form form .submit").clone().insertAfter($(this)).attr("disabled","true");
                $(".consult-form form .submit").hide();
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/web-contact']); // Google Page Tracker
                $.post('/path/to/process.php', $(".consult-form form").serialize(), function(data) {
                    // Add Thank You Message
                    $('.thank-you-message').html(data);
                    // Create IFRAME to page with Adwords Tracking Script
                    function ppcconversion() {
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.style.width = '0px';
                        iframe.style.height = '0px';
                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                        iframe.src = 'http://www.fullurlto.com/conversion-script.php';
                    };
                    ppcconversion();
                });
                return false; // I attempted to add this line to prevent it from submitting multiple times. It didn't work.
                $(".consult-form form").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If there are any other details you need for more insight just let me know and I'll provide them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're adding a new validation handler on each click of `.submit`

Instead add the validation once in the `ready` handler

```
$(function() {
    $(".consult-form form").validationEngine('attach', {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. I understand what you're suggesting, but I'm not sure how to edit my code accordingly. Sorry I'm not overly experienced. Could you provide more detailed examples in your answer?

Comment: Replace `$(".consult-form form .submit").click(function(){` with `$(function() {`

Comment: Oh haha, okay easy enough. I've made the update to my code. I think this was probably the issue but I'll make it as the right answer after some testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validation engine is normally triggered on form submit, so there's no need to bind on the submit button click event.

Just stick with attaching the validation ending to the form and submitting normally. Should be good (not tested)

Comment: Cool. I made the changes Andreas suggested (same as you mentioned). Hopefully this solves my problem.